# How to broadcast to all clients in a room as room owner where roomID is the same as ownerID

Tags: socket.io

I am creating a multiplayer game using websockets, and am implementing each game room using a websocket room, where the room is the owners default websocket room. Clients will then join that room to join the game.

The issue arises when I attempt to broadcast, as the owner, to all clients who have joined the room. When this happens, the clients do not receive anything.

Here is some sample code:

```js
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import { createServer } from 'http'
import express from 'express';

enum Events {
    JOIN = 'join',
    BROADCAST = 'broadcast',
    MESSAGE = 'message',
}

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected with id: ', socket.id);

    socket.on(Events.JOIN, (roomId: string) => {
        if (!roomId) return;
        socket.join(roomId);
    });

    socket.on(Events.BROADCAST, (roomId) => {
        socket.to(roomId).emit(Events.MESSAGE, "something");
    }
    )
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Here is what happens:

1. I join the server with 2 clients, lets say their assigned ids are a and b
2. b joins a's room by calling the join Event with a as the roomId
3. a broadcasts by calling the broadcast Event with a as the roomId
4. b does NOT receive any message

I was expecting b to receive the "something" message.
NOTE: If I send a broadcast with b, a gets the "something" message, its only when the owner sends the message do none of the members of the room get the broadcast.